# Convert the below logic in oracle tree

Tags: sql, oracle

Recursively the parent is inserted first and then the children. How can I migrate the logic in Oracle using parent-child.The logic for the SQL should be first the parent is evaluated and then inserted or added and then the child is checked and then it is prepared.

Thank you for the response , the table structure as follow Name

```
REF_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER        
REF_TYPE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER        
PARENT_REF_ID          NUMBER        
REF_VALUE     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)
```

Now the expected result conditions:  we need to start finding the query with ref_id, so if ref_id is supposed 14, then we need to check the corresponding should have parent_ref_id is null or not, if parent_ref_id is present suppose 4, then we need to again get the value for 4 as ref_id and check is parent_id is null or not If null then we need to check the value ref_type_id whether it is 1, 2,3,4,..; etc and based on the condition we need to append the result 4(parent_ref_id) with some text let it be 'article 4'. Now resuming back to the loop, the user had enter ref_id 14, then we need to check the value for ref_type_id for the corresponding and then we need to append with the result suppose 'par 14' and this result had to come after parent result: **article 4 par 14** (article 4 - parent, par 14 children)

Comment: Can you share the table structure as it exists in the database and the output you are trying to achieve along with some sample data? That would make your question much easier to answer. Also, what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I had updated the description for the questions above

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear with my previous comment. Can you provide a table with some sample data and what result you would expect from that sample data? Thank you

Comment: Updated the description again with data and example and expected

Comment: Can I execute the query in SQL developer? Because yesterday I was unable to work with SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH  in SQL developer.

Comment: yes, you can execute the query in SQL Developer. It's possible you had a syntax error that was preventing you previously.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using a `CONNECT BY` statement with `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` should be able to help you achieve your goal.

```sql
WITH
    refs (ref_id,
          ref_type_id,
          parent_ref_id,
          ref_value)
    AS
        (SELECT 501, 1, NULL, 207 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 502, 2, 501, 4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 503, 3, 502, 1 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT r.ref_id as starting_ref_id,
           TRIM (
               ',' FROM
                   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (
                          CASE r.ref_type_id
                              WHEN 1 THEN 'article '
                              WHEN 2 THEN 'par '
                              WHEN 3 THEN '('
                              WHEN 4 THEN 'point '
                              WHEN 5 THEN 'sous '
                              WHEN 6 THEN NULL
                              WHEN 8 THEN NULL
                              ELSE '/'
                          END
                       || r.ref_id,
                       ','))    AS ref_label
      FROM refs r
     WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR r.parent_ref_id = r.ref_id;

   STARTING_REF_ID                   REF_LABEL
__________________ ___________________________
               501 article 501
               502 par 502,article 501
               503 (503,par 502,article 501
```

Comment: I had checked the result for the query and the result is  501 +article 501                                                     +502 par 502+article 501 , I am trying to replace + by , and also I don't need + in the starting for the result

Comment: The sample data you provided would not produce the result you are describing. I have also replaced `+` with `,` in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, one last request I would like the result instead of                        
  502             par 502,article 501  expected as                                                                
  502             article 501,par 502 (reverse order) how can I achieve this?